# Passing parameters to unwrap_or method for HashMap.get() in Rust

Tags: rust

Please review the following code snippet

```
let mut frequency: HashMap<char, i16> = HashMap::new();
frequency.insert('a', freq.get(&'a').unwrap_or(&0) + 1);
```

I have two questions on the above code.

1. Is this the right way to insert a (key, value) into the HashMap with an incremented value?
2. Why do we need to pass "&0" (and not 0) in the  `unwrap_or` method?
   Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for inserting an incremented value: You are looking for [`HashMap::entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry). It's example shows how to build a counter just like you need:

> ```rust
> use std::collections::HashMap;
>
> let mut letters = HashMap::new();
>
> for ch in "a short treatise on fungi".chars() {
>     letters.entry(ch).and_modify(|counter| *counter += 1).or_insert(1);
> }
>
> assert_eq!(letters[&'u'], 1);
> assert_eq!(letters.get(&'y'), None);
> ```

`entry` avoids duplicate lookups (in your case there's `insert` *and* `get` - both of them require to determine the position of `a`, `entry` avoids the second lookup).

As for why you need `&0`: `get` returns a *reference* to the element from the map. If there's no element there, `unwrap_or` can be used to supply a default value - but this has to be of the same type: reference. Thus, you need `&0` in this case.